# Is this Mr. Spock in Sei Juushi Bismarck?

Tags: sei-jushi-bismark

In episode 18 of *Sei Juushi Bismarck*, at around 6:30, I just noticed a character looking very similar to Mr. Spock from Star Trek to the right. I checked the scene of the corresponding episode, **The Amazing Lazardo**, in [Saber Rider and the Star Sherrifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_Rider_and_the_Star_Sheriffs) but the character does not appear there. The scene pans from left to right but stops before the character appears on screen.

*Bismark* aired from 1984-1985 in Japan and *Star Trek: The Animated Series* aired from [1973-1974 in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Animated_Series) and [1977 in Japan](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E5%AE%87%E5%AE%99%E5%A4%A7%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%A6).  It seems to me that somebody noticed this during editing and thought it's best to leave the character out. Does anybody have any background about this?

[image]

Comment: Nice find :) I could not find any information regarding why this was done but I'm pretty sure that's Spock, considering the popularity of Star Trek back then. To me, it's probably more like a nod to a popular character rather than an indication that both series' universes are connected. I might be wrong, though...